weiterpennen - keep sleeping?
I have heard the following sentence in the Schalfende Hunde TV series:

Schätze, LKA kann weiterpennen.

Context: A group of detectives was called to investigate blood coming down from the ceiling in the apartment of an old lady. They broke in the above apartment and found a dead woman in the floor. She likely was drunk, slipped and got cut with a bottle. One of the detectives is summarizing the case. Possibly relevant fact is the detective that broke in the apartment ended up hitting a child that was behind the front door. Maybe the speaker doesn't want to get LKA involved due to that or because the case is already sorted out ?
The meaning of "weiterpennen" in DWDS is "keep sleeping". Not sure what this means in this context. I can't find a suitable meaning for "pennen" in DWDS or Word Reference either.

Most of your mentioned context doesn't seem relevant (But thanks for including it anyway, you never know).
The LKA is a superior state authority to normal (local) police, only to be involved in special cases of public interest or organized crime. Thus, the normal police only see them working sporadically, so they could simply assume they would be sleeping (tounge-in-cheek) most of the time. Also, there seems to be a bit of a tradition of friction between state and local police.
This is a way of saying that the officers seem to assume the case in question is not one of that special ones, but rather trivial or even an accident, so the LKA doesn't need to be involved and they can continue to "sleep".


The meaning of "weiterpennen" in DWDS is "keep sleeping". Not sure what this means in this context.

Let use first clear "pennen": this is a word used in the northern and middle regions of the German-speaking area and means "to sleep". It can (but not necessarily so) have a negative connotation, e.g. in "Penner" (homeless or jobless one, but also used as an insult). The word comes from Rotwelsch but where it did come from to there isn't clear. Some scholars (i.e. Kluge/Seebold, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) suppose western Yiddish ("pannai" = "idle")
Next is the (small, but subtle) difference between "weiter pennen" and "weiterpennen". We recently had a question specifically dealing with this and it is a common German trait that composite words change their meaning when written together or apart.
The "weiter" in "weiter pennen" in this context means simply to continue to and is a qualifier to the verb. The same way you could say "weiter gehen", "weiter lesen", etc.:

Ich will weiter gehen.
I want to continue to walk.

But the continuing aspect is not part of the verb: "weiter gehen" implies something like "continue to walk instead of e.g. driving":

Ich will weiter gehen und nicht fahren.

In "weitergehen", on the other hand, this continuing aspect is part of the verb itself: "weitergehen" describes the action of continuing to go, which is why "weitergehen" has a second derived meaning of "to go on" or "to carry on". "Das Leben muß weitergehen." could be a comment said to someone who has lost a dear one, meaning you have to get over it, because life has to go on.
Coming back to "weiterpennen": weiterpennen is not the continued action of sleeping but the action of continuing to sleep. This is difficult to explain (and perhaps even more difficult to understand) because English doesn't have this difference. "Weiter pennen" is something you could do after someone wakes you up: you decide upon getting up or not and decide for continuing to sleep further. "Weiterpennen", on the other hand, is what one does when he is not woken up. e.g. A asks B if he should wake up C and B answers:

Nein, lass' ihn doch weiterpennen.

In your case the "LKA" (Landeskriminalamt, a state police organisation, loosely comparable to State Bureau of Investigation in the US) is considered "sleeping" (that is: doing nothing) and hence:

(Ich) Schätze, (das) LKA kann weiterpennen.

means the organisation can continue to do nothing - nothing to see there.
